# What is the 'counterpart' of unprecedented?

Tags: antonyms

I'm not looking for the literal antonym. Unprecedented means 'never seen/happened before then', but what is the word for 'never seen/happened ***since*** then'?

I have a feeling it might be unrepeated, but that doesn't really sound like an actual word.

Comment: In the climbing world, *unseconded* is a term for a peak that has only been climbed once. It usually applies to free solo efforts or clean unaided assents. [Then one rainy day, he {Paul Pritchard} and Glenn Robbins rappelled to the base of Gogarth for an ascent of Games Climbers Play, the unseconded difficult and dangerous route put up by the legendary Pat Littlejohn in 1979, and to this day hasn't seen a second ascent.](https://www.bigwalls.net/climb/PaulP.html)

Comment: There's "unequaled".  Doesn't have quite the meaning requested, but is often used, especially as "unequaled since".

Answer (score 1):

The closest match I can come up with is **never-to-be-repeated**.

Though it's not easy to find defined as a lexeme, it's common on the internet.

> A never to be repeated experience - Ennio Morricone plays his last
>   ever Irish Concert.
>   [[facebook](https://www.facebook.com/mcd.productions/photos/a-never-to-be-repeated-experience-ennio-morricone-plays-his-last-ever-irish-conc/10155505456829548/)]

................

> a never to be repeated special offer 
>    - Willis' Walkabouts [[facebook](https://www.facebook.com/bushwalkingholidays/posts/a-never-to-be-repeated-special-offerthe-four-photos-here-were-taken-on-our-mitch/10156187413476928/)]

................

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repeat) has an example using the same string, but not as a premodifier:

> This is an offer never to be repeated.

The term is not entirely well-defined, as it can carry either the 'it is not intended that this be repeated' or 'this was the last time it took place' sense.